# Get uploaded file as stream using Express

Tags: node.js, express, http, file-upload, upload

Right now, I'm trying to make an API, and one of its functions is to take a file and upload it to another website, sort of like uploading a file through the API as some sort of "proxy".

The website I'm sending the file to requires additional steps to work (namely sending the destination in another request) and I wanted to have my API do that all in one request instead, where that request already had all the details needed.

I've gotten the request for the destination done, but I'm having a hard time finding out how to "pipe" the upload of a user into the request that I send to the website. `request-promise` takes a file stream as an input when uploading files, so I wanted to hopefully pipe the upload coming from the user to the request. That way I don't have to use any disk space to temporarily save the file, especially since I'm very limited in disk space and since the server I'm sending it to virtually has no file limit.

As of now, I'm using `express-fileupload` to temporarily save the file, but this will eventually blow up my extremely small (194 MB) allocated space. I'm using `express` v4.16.4 and Node v12.0.0. For the requests, I use `request-promise` v4.2.4.

Here's how I declared the Express app and the `express-fileupload` object.

```js
var router = express.Router({ caseSensitive: true });
app.use(router);

...

router.use(require("express-fileupload")({
    useTempFiles : true,
    tempFileDir : ".data/temp"
}));
```

And here's what I'm using to toss the file into the website:

```js
if (req.body.id === undefined || req.files.file === undefined)
    return new APIError(400);
if (!Object.keys(JSON.parse(fs.read(".data/master_list_of_possible_values_for_that_variable.json"))).includes(req.body.id))
    return new APIError("400-ID");

var session_flag = await(session.executeRequest({
    method: "POST",
    uri: Constants.URL.upload.session,
    form: {
        id: req.body.id
    }
})
    .then(r => {return r;})
    .catch(e => { return e; }));

if (session_flag instanceof Error)
    throw session_flag;

var upload = await(session.executeRequest({
    method: "POST",
    uri: Constants.URL.upload.fileEndpoint,
    formData: {
        file: {
            value: fs.createReadStream(req.files.file.tempFilePath),
            options: {
                filename: req.files.file.name,
                contentType: req.files.file.mimetype
            }
        }
    }
})
    .then(r => {return r;})
    .catch(e => { return e; }));

if (upload instanceof Error)
    throw upload;

return { success: true };
```

Comment: Can you show what you have already? Because all you need to do is: `req.pipe(request)`, specially the additional step you mention.

Comment: Alright, I've added the code I use for catching the request, sending the initial request, then sending the actual file.

Also, I can't see a `req.pipe` in the Express documentation. Is this a new thing?

Comment: Additionally, I have to submit the first request before having to pipe the request to the website, and the parameter that handles that is also in the body. Doesn't this mean I have to read the entire body (which includes the file) first?

Comment: Do you control the front end? Because the only thing I see that you need to post is: `id`

Comment: I do control the front end of the application I'm making, but not the website I'm sending the file to, which (for reasons I don't know) requires two separate requests for it to work, namely sending `id` on one URL, then sending the actual file on another.

Comment: Check my answer, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest you do, is the following:

1. Change your endpoint so you send `id` in the URL, that way you don't need to read the whole body to issue the first request
2. Pipe the request directly to the third party endpoint

```js
const request = require('request'); // streaming works better with request
const rp = require('request-promise');
const { once } = require('events');

// Make sure you don't have any body parser enable for this request
router.post('/:id', async(req, res) => {
   try {

        // issue first request
        await rp({
            method: "POST",
            uri: Constants.URL.upload.session,
            form: {
                id: req.body.id
            }
        })
        // pipe request
        const upload = req.pipe(request({
            method: "POST",
            uri: Constants.URL.upload.fileEndpoint,
            headers: req.headers // Send Same Content-Type, Length and so on
        }))

        // will throw on 'error'
        await once(upload, 'response')

        // check status code if you want
        const success = upload.response.statusCode === 200;

        return res.json({ success })

   } catch(e) {
      res.status(500)
        .send('error')
   }
});
```

Doing this, you don't need to store it in a temporary file since you're piping it directly to the third party endpoint.

Comment: Thank you! Just a little follow-up: Is there any way to check if the body contains the correct file?

Comment: Yes, there is, but it's a bit complicated, depending on the file type you may need to read the whole file. I recommend you let the third party server check for it, unless you have a good reason to check it yourself.

Comment: How about checking if the request in fact contains a file? Do I just have to check if `req.body` is undefined?

Comment: We're using streams, you don't have the whole file, `req.body` is empty or it should be, make sure you don't use any body parser for that request. What extensions do you need to check for?

Comment: I just have to find out if the request contains a file (so I can provide a response accordingly that they're missing that in the request.) As far as I'm aware, I don't think I have to check the extension.

Comment: I don't mean the file extension, but what fily types are you expecting. images, videos, text files, zips

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203560/discussion-between-chlod-alejandro-and-marcos-casagrande).