# Pass Express request onto Axios POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, node-streams

I'm trying to pass an Express request straight into an Axios request. I'm using this endpoint as more of a proxy or a relay, although I have to modify the headers of the request, namely the `Authorization` and `Cookie` headers. I'm also relaying this in such way that I don't have to use any disk space or RAM space. I did ask [a question like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59164411/get-uploaded-file-as-stream-using-express) before, but it was for `request-promise`, which I am switching from. The code doesn't work when I replace the variables, so it doesn't really work. So far, I have this:

```js
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://example.com/json_upload',
        responseType: "stream",
        headers: {
           'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + req.params["fileHash"]
        }
    }).then((res) => {
        req.pipe(res.data);
    });
});
```

As you can see, the Express request parameter "fileHash" is used for the Bearer token, and I tried to pipe the request to Axios, but this does not work, and I get the following error:

```
TypeError: dest.end is not a function
    at IncomingMessage.onend (_stream_readable.js:671:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

I have tried to switch it around and use the response to pipe to the data, but this means I wouldn't stream the request body to the Axios request. I haven't found any other solution to this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer help you fix your problem?

Comment: It does work in forwarding the response, but I also have to forward the data stored in the request body. I forgot to add that in the question. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `axiosResponse.data.pipe(res);`. Also, you can remove `async/await` as you are using `.then`.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://example.com/json_upload',
        responseType: "stream",
        headers: {
           'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + req.params["fileHash"]
        }
    }).then((axiosResponse) => {
        axiosResponse.data.pipe(res);
    });
});
```